# Outlook REST API - Get logged in user's email address

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

How do I get the logged in user's email address using Outlook REST API?

I'm using `com.microsoft.services.outlook.fetchers.OutlookClient` (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java/blob/master/sdk/outlook-services/src/main/java/com/microsoft/services/outlook/fetchers/OutlookClient.java).

Is extracting it from the JWT access token the only way (see [here](http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142) and [here](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutor)) ?
(Latest changes to tokens [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-preview-oidc-changes/))

Thanks

UPDATE:
Following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26519738/4317945ial/dotnet):

- Get the Inbox parent folder ID:

  `mClient.getMe().getMailFolders().getById("Inbox").read()`

  `inboxMailFolderResult.getParentFolderId()`
- Get the parent folder display name using the ID retrieved

  `mClient.getMe().getMailFolders().getById("ID_RETRIEVED_AAA==").read()`

  `parentMailFolderResult.getDisplayName()`

..doesn't seem to work either, I just get *Top of Information Store* as display name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Office 365 SDK for Java only provide the Outlook service at present. We can also get the email address of the sign-in user through the metadata via making the REST directly.
Here is the REST request for your reference:

```
GET: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me
authorization: bearer {Token}
```

You would get the response like below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the info I needed. So a simple `mClient.getMe().read()` will work for me. +1

Comment: There's no way to fetch email aliases also associated with the account is there?

Answer (score 1):

Following FeiXue's answer this is the code needed:

```
Futures.addCallback(mClient.getMe().read(), new FutureCallback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(User result) {
        Log.d("APP", "Logged in user's email address: "+result.getEmailAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Email fetch failure. Cause:", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```