# Office365 / Outlook: Get user's email addresses or aliases

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi, outlook-api

Essentially, I'd like to know what email addresses I have permissions to send emails from. Is it possible to get this information via the REST API? E.g., my primary mailbox is fname.lname@live.com, but I've also added the alias fname.lname.test@outlook.com to this account and can send emails from both addresses.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768014/outlook-rest-api-get-logged-in-users-email-address), I've tried using the `GET: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me` API but it only returns the primary fname.lname@live.com address.

Comment: Also looking to pull this via the REST API as well.  Were you able to find the answer?  Seeing the same results as you (only main email is shown with the /me call.